# Function contains() on a non-object Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

```
 $profiles = UserProfile::find(1)->user_id;
 if ($profiles->contains($uid)){
     // ...
 }
```

**Error:** `Call to a member function contains() on a non-object`.

Any idea what did I do wrong? I'm trying to check if the user already has got a row in the table.

Comment: Are you sure `UserProfile::find(1)->user_id` is returning what you expect? This would seem to imply that `$profiles` is a non-object, like possibly `FALSE` or `NULL` if the user was not found.

Comment: try to check gettype($profiles) and see if $profiles is an object or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `$profiles` is not an object because, you have used

```
// returns "user_id" from the collection
$profiles = UserProfile::find(1)->user_id;
```

So, `$profiles` contains the value of field `user_id` not the `UserProfile` object. If you use

```
$profiles = UserProfile::find(1);
```

Then it'll return `UserProfile` object if there is an `id` of `1` available in the table. So, you can use

```
if ( $profiles->contains($uid) ) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `UserProfile::find(1)->user_id` returns a **number** or a **string** and not an **object**
SO `$profiles->contains($uid)` will not work for you.

Comment: It returns a string , hmm any alternative?

Comment: As far as I know **UserProfile::find(1)** will return an object for you

Comment: If i do that i will get Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::contains() , issue with models?